# MS Access - Basic Relationship Error

Tags: ms-access, relationships

I am trying to create a simple database of a theoretical car rental company. The following picture shows the relationships I currently have.

[image]

However, when I try to assign more than one car to a single customer, I get the following error message:

[image]

If anyone could advise me as to why this is coming up and what to change I would be very greatful, if more information is needed to figure this out just ask! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ER diagram's wrong.
Assuming you want Zero, One Customer --> Many Cars, then the proper pattern is to insert the foreign key of the 0,1 into the table of the Many.

So your Cars table should have a Foreign key of CustomerId.

Customer table shouldn't know about Cars at all for normality.

EDIT:
Looking at the requirements/model, chances are this is many to many.
I.e. Many customers over time rent a car or cars.
In this case to maintain normality you need a junction table - e.g. cars-customers that has two primary keys, CustomerId and CarId.
That's also where you'd put information about that relationship, like dates rented and the like.

Answer (score 2):

`CustomerID` is a primary key, and is being duplicated on your second line. Primary keys must be unique.

You have created a 1 to 1 relationship between customers and bookings. That means that every customer may have only one booking and every booking may only have one customer. That's why you are having to duplicate that `CustomerID` in order to add a booking with a different car.

Comment: This is the better answer. A junction table is not required. Bookings should simply have its own auto number PK. You can then add as many bookings to a customer as you want, and to each booking you add a car – this could be the same car booked on difference occasions, or a you can attach many bookings to the customer with a different car. I up voted this post and down voted Going's post since as correctly pointed out some junction table is not required but only a minor change to table bookings. Once done, then "many" bookings are possible and we simply attach a car to that booking.